# Исключить перенаправление .htaccess, если пользователь находится в админке

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, redirect

Добрый день!

По заданию сеошников залил в .htaccess правило для перенаправления со страниц без слеша на страницы без слеша:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Не пойму, как сюда добавить правило, чтобы редирект не срабатывал, если в URL есть строка `/backend/`, т.е пользователь находится в админке.

**Обновление**

У нас не CMS, у нас тут какой-то самопал на Zend. )) Не буду называть клиента, скажу лишь, что это очень крупная торговая сеть, представленная в 40 городах России и СНГ, просто миллионные обороты, а сайт написали какие-то студенты на Zend. Причём какого-либо нереального функционала (потребовавшего использование фрэймворка) на сайте нет. Можно было бы обойтись битриксом редакцией "Старнт" за 5000 рублей. Меня всегда поражало, как такие заказчики умудряются выйти на таких исполнителей!??. =)

Comment: У вас CMS??? типа джумлы

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте вот это условие:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend(/(.*)|$)
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало!